# replacing id and name using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace `id` and `name` of `input` using javascript regular expression not sure what is wrong with my regular expression

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TotalValue must be a number." id="Notice_NoticeDetails_0__TotalValue" name="Notice.NoticeDetails[0].TotalValue" type="text" value="">
```

regular expression test is selecting correct string ( test below)

https://www.regextester.com/?fam=108441
https://www.regextester.com/?fam=108442

However when i use the same expression in javascript its not replacing the string

```js
var $input = $("input");
$input.prop("name", $input.prop("name").replace("/\[.*?\]/g", "[2]"));
$input.prop("id", $input.prop("id").replace("/\_.d?\__/g", "_2__"));
alert($input.prop("name"));
alert($input.prop("id"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TotalValue must be a number." id="Notice_NoticeDetails_0__TotalValue" name="Notice.NoticeDetails[0].TotalValue" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Can you post all the relevant code in the question itself, so that the question is on-topic? What exactly are you inputting where, and what sort of behavior were you expecting instead?

Comment: `"/\[.*?\]/g"` is a string, not a regular expression. A regular expression literal starts and ends with `/`, so drop the quotes: `.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, "[2]")`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove quotes around the regexps. In JS regexps are introduced in parsing by `/`, they are not strings .

```js
var $input = $("input");
$input.attr("name", $input.prop("name").replace(/\[.*?\]/g, "[2]"));
$input.attr("id", $input.prop("id").replace(/\_.d?\__/g, "_2__"));
alert($input.attr("name"));
alert($input.attr("id"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TotalValue must be a number." id="Notice_NoticeDetails_0__TotalValue" name="Notice.NoticeDetails[0].TotalValue" type="text" value="">
```